# How to get single value in php instead of $stmt->fetchObject();

Tags: php

This is my function.

```
public function getOrderValue($order_id) {
    $sql = "select SUM(OD.quantity * OD.product_sell_price) from table_order_details OD where OD.order_id= :order_id AND OD.is_delete = 0";
    try {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("order_id", $order_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->fetchObject();
        return $user;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return NULL;
        //echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```

As there is only single column in query, How to return that value? Basically i want how to fetch SUM alone instead of returning an object $stmt->fetchObject();

Comment: Please be specific about the framework you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fetchColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php), but there is nothing wrong with returning `$user->total` or something similar.

```
public function getOrderValue($order_id) {
$sql = "SELECT SUM(OD.quantity * OD.product_sell_price) AS total FROM table_order_details OD WHERE OD.order_id= :order_id AND OD.is_delete = 0";
try {
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("order_id", $order_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $total = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    return $total;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    return NULL;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using PDO, you could use fetchColumn

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php